# How to generate a makefile by qmake and use it without Qt enviromment

Tags: makefile, qmake

Write a normal C++ project using Qt IDE and then
Compile it with a makefile generated by qmake on another machine without qmake.

Comment: Simply `CONFIG -= qt`.

Comment: it doesn't work。qmake: Command not found

Comment: If you already have a makefile generated by qmake, then you don't need qmake anymore.